# subfolders not being created when deployed to target folders in SSRS c#

Tags: c#, reporting-services, deployment

I have a c# solution that creates folders in SSRS where I store my reports, data sources, data sets and images, however I seem to be experimenting an issue when deploying files to a new folder when one already exists on root that is populated with other SSRS files. I'm using reporting services 2010.

This is my Folder Hirearchy

[image]

This is the folder created by my first deployment even though there was an empty folder already created

[image]

Notice that the sub folders Data Source, Reports, ect are created and so the SSRS files populated inside, so no problem there, however when I try a second deployment this is what happens

[image]

It only creates the Data Set subfolder, without its data source

I tried creating the Other_Custom_SSRS with only the empty folder and the same thing happens, Other_Custom_SSRS has all its subfolders and files, yet when I create the Custom_SSRS folder afterwards, only the DataSet subolder is created.

The error messages I keep getting are:

```
File dataSource.rds: Error was System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The item '/Other_Custom_SSRS/Data Source' cannot be found. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item '/Other_Custom_SSRS/Data Source' cannot be found.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2010Impl.CreateDataSource(String DataSource, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, DataSourceDefinition Definition, Property[] Properties, String ParameterName, CatalogItem& ItemInfo)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.CreateDataSource(String DataSource, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, DataSourceDefinition Definition, Property[] Properties, CatalogItem& ItemInfo).

File Report.rdl: Error was System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The item '/Other_Custom_SSRS/Reports' cannot be found. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item 'Other_Custom_SSRS' cannot be found.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2010Impl.CreateReport(String Report, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, ItemType ItemType, CatalogItem& ItemInfo, Warning[]& Warnings)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2010Impl.CreateCatalogItem(String ItemType, String Name, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, CatalogItem& ItemInfo, Warning[]& Warnings)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.CreateCatalogItem(String ItemType, String Name, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, CatalogItem& ItemInfo, Warning[]& Warnings).

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The item '/Other_Custon_SSRS/Reports' cannot be found. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item '/Other_Custon_SSRS/Reports' cannot be found.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2010Impl.CreateReport(String Report, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, ItemType ItemType, CatalogItem& ItemInfo, Warning[]& Warnings)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2010Impl.CreateCatalogItem(String ItemType, String Name, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, CatalogItem& ItemInfo, Warning[]& Warnings)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.CreateCatalogItem(String ItemType, String Name, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, CatalogItem& ItemInfo, Warning[]& Warnings)'
```

Code:

```
public bool CreateFolderHierarchy(ReportingService2010 ssrsProxy)
    {
        CatalogItem[] folderItems = new CatalogItem[] {};

        try
        {
            folderItems = ssrsProxy.ListChildren("/", true);

            if (!CheckFolderExists(staffmPathName, folderItems))
            {
                ssrsProxy.CreateFolder(staffmPathName, "/", null);
            }

            folderItems = ssrsProxy.ListChildren("/", true);

            if (CheckFolderExists(staffmPathName, folderItems))
            {
                if (!CheckFolderExists(reportFolderName, folderItems))
                {
                    ssrsProxy.CreateFolder(reportFolderName, staffmPath, null);
                }

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(targetImagesFolder))
                {
                    if (!CheckFolderExists(imagesFolderName, folderItems))
                    {
                        ssrsProxy.CreateFolder(imagesFolderName, staffmPath, null);
                    }
                }

                if (!CheckFolderExists(DataSourcePathName, folderItems))
                {
                    ssrsProxy.CreateFolder(DataSourcePathName, staffmPath, null);
                }

                if (!CheckFolderExists(DataSet_FolderName, folderItems))
                {
                    ssrsProxy.CreateFolder(DataSet_FolderName, staffmPath, null);
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

       public string CreateDataSource(ReportingService2010 ssrsProxy, ref bool bHasErrors, ref bool errorFlag,
        string rdsFilePath)
    {
        try
        {
            var rdsf = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(rdsFilePath);
            //Load datasource xml and create new data source with proper paths and references.
            XmlDocument Rds = new XmlDocument();
            Rds.Load(rdsFilePath);
            var ConnProps = Rds.SelectSingleNode("RptDataSource").SelectSingleNode("ConnectionProperties");
            var type = ssrsProxy.GetType().Namespace;
            var datatype = (type + ".DataSourceDefinition");
            var datatype_Prop = (type + ".Property");
            Property[] properties = new Property[]
                {PropertyFactory(datatype_Prop, DescProperty), PropertyFactory(datatype_Prop, HiddenProperty)};
            var Definition = (DataSourceDefinition) Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(datatype));
            Definition.ConnectString = ConnProps.SelectSingleNode("ConnectString").FirstChild.Value;
            Definition.Extension = ConnProps.SelectSingleNode("Extension").FirstChild.Value;

            if (ConnProps.SelectSingleNode("IntegratedSecurity") != null &&
                Convert.ToBoolean(ConnProps.SelectSingleNode("IntegratedSecurity").FirstChild.Value))
            {
                Definition.CredentialRetrieval = CredentialRetrievalEnum.Integrated;
            }

            if (Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(IsOverwriteDataSource)))
            {
                ssrsProxy.CreateDataSource(rdsf, targetDataSourceFolder,
                    Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(IsOverwriteDataSource)), Definition, properties);
            }
            else //If not set to overwrite the data source, ignore error of data source already exists
            {
                try
                {
                    ssrsProxy.CreateDataSource(rdsf, targetDataSourceFolder,
                        Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(IsOverwriteDataSource)), Definition, properties);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (ex.Message != null &&
                        ex.Message.Contains($"The item '{targetDataSourceFolder}/{rdsf}' already exists."))
                    {
                        //If not set to overwrite the data source, ignore error of data source already exists
                    }
                    else
                        throw;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            bHasErrors = true;
            errorFlag = true;
            if (e.InnerException != null)
                return
                    string.Format("File: {2}: Error was {0}. Detail was {1}", e.Message, e.InnerException.ToString(),
                        Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(rdsFilePath)) + Constants.vbNewLine;
            else
                return
                    string.Format("File {1}: Error was {0}.", e.Message,
                        Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(rdsFilePath)) + Constants.vbNewLine;
        }

        return "";
    }

public string CreateReport(ReportingService2010 ssrsProxy, ref bool bHasErrors, ref bool errorFlag,
            string rdlFilePath)
        {
            var reportFolder_Final = staffmPath + targetReportFolder;

        var reportName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(rdlFilePath);
        try
        {
            //Get Report Content
            var byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(rdlFilePath);
            var type = ssrsProxy.GetType().Namespace;
            var datatype_Prop = (type + ".Property");
            Property[] properties = new Property[]
                {PropertyFactory(datatype_Prop, DescProperty), PropertyFactory(datatype_Prop, HiddenProperty)};

            //Create the report
            Warning[] warnings = null;
            CatalogItem results = null;
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(isOverwriteReport)))
            {
                results = ssrsProxy.CreateCatalogItem("Report", reportName, reportFolder_Final,
                    Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(isOverwriteReport)), byteArray, properties, out warnings);
            }
            else //If not set to overwrite the report, ignore error of report already exists
            {
                try
                {
                    results = ssrsProxy.CreateCatalogItem("Report", reportName, reportFolder_Final,
                        Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(isOverwriteReport)), byteArray, properties, out warnings);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (ex.Message != null &&
                        ex.Message.Contains($"The item '{reportFolder_Final}/{reportName}' already exists."))
                    {
                        //If not set to overwrite the report, ignore error of report already exists
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }

            var reportFullName = reportFolder_Final + @"/" + reportName;
            var rep = ssrsProxy.GetItemReferences(reportFullName, "DataSet");

            //Change Data Set reference on report
            foreach (ItemReferenceData ir in rep)
            {
                var proxyNamespace = ir.GetType().Namespace;
                string pathName = "";
                if (ir.Name == "dsRSTSTFMEmployeeClass")
                {
                    pathName = "dsRSTSTFMEmployeeClassification";
                }
                else if (ir.Name == "dsGPEmployeeClass")
                {
                    pathName = "dsGPEmployeeClassification";
                }
                else
                {
                    pathName = ir.Name;
                }
                var dsPath = targetDatasetFolder + @"/" + pathName;
                var reference = (ItemReference)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(proxyNamespace + ".ItemReference"));
                reference.Name = ir.Name;
                reference.Reference = dsPath;
                var references = new ItemReference[] { reference };
                ssrsProxy.SetItemReferences(reportFullName, references);
            }
            
            //Toggle for overwriting custom data source with shared data source.
            if (isOverwriteReportDataSource == "1")
            {
                //Get existing data source
                ReportService2010.DataSource[] itemDataSources = ssrsProxy.GetItemDataSources(reportFullName);

                //Change Data Source reference on report
                foreach (ReportService2010.DataSource itemDataSource in itemDataSources)
                {
                    var proxyNamespace = itemDataSource.GetType().Namespace;
                    var constDatasource = (DataSource)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(proxyNamespace + ".DataSource"));
                    constDatasource.Item = (DataSourceReference)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(proxyNamespace + ".DataSourceReference"));
                    var FinalDataSourcePath = targetDataSourceFolder + @"/" + MainDataSourceName; //MainDataSourceName
                    var r = (DataSourceReference)constDatasource.Item;
                    r.Reference = FinalDataSourcePath;
                    itemDataSource.Item = r;
                    ssrsProxy.SetItemDataSources(reportFullName, itemDataSources);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            bHasErrors = true;
            errorFlag = true;
            if (e.InnerException != null)
                return string.Format("File: {2}: Error was {0}. Detail was {1}", e.Message, e.InnerException.ToString(), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(rdlFilePath)) + Constants.vbNewLine;
            else
                return string.Format("File {1}: Error was {0}.", e.Message, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(rdlFilePath)) + Constants.vbNewLine;
        }

        return "";
    }


 private bool CheckFolderExists(string folderName, CatalogItem[] files)
    {
        return files.ToList().Any(x => x.Name == folderName);
    }
```

I've researched and so far all the fixes involve VS deployment with the Report Builder or manual creation of the folders in SSRS, but I want to do it by code. Changing the folder herierchy is out of the question, I can't create the subfolders on Home and assign all reports to a Reports folder, I need to organize them by project. If anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this line of code

```
folderItems = ssrsProxy.ListChildren(staffmPath, true);
```

under  `if (CheckFolderExists(staffmPathName, folderItems))`

turns out it want creating the folders because when it checked if the item existed in the foldersItems object, it would return true. The folderItems object was listing the children of Home and since there was already a folder named "Reports" and "Data Source" and so on, it wouldn't create it.